# could not extract ResultSet in Hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have problem trying authenticate user using spring security and extracting users from the db. I am using Postgres for this purpose and I am sure it is configured because I am able to manipulate entities from other tables. Here is the error I receive:

```
    org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:143)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1897)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    at com.musala.ving.serviceimpl.MyUserDetailsService.buildUserAuthority(MyUserDetailsService.java:49)
    at com.musala.ving.serviceimpl.MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(MyUserDetailsService.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy211.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column userrole0_.user_id does not exist
  Position: 8
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 69 more
```

Here is my User class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "DEFAULT_ROOM")
    private String defaultRoom;

    @Column(name = "VOICEMAIL_BOX")
    private String voicemailBox;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "USERS_ROOMS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID") })
    private Set<Room> rooms = new LinkedHashSet<Room>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private Set<Extension> extensions = new HashSet<Extension>();

    @Column(name = "LOGIN_PIN")
    private String loginPin;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    @Column(name = "ENABLED")
    private boolean enabled;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getVoicemailBox() {
        return voicemailBox;
    }

    public void setVoicemailBox(String voicemailBox) {
        this.voicemailBox = voicemailBox;
    }

    public Set<Room> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public void setRooms(Set<Room> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public Set<Extension> getExtensions() {
        return extensions;
    }

    public void setExtensions(Set<Extension> extensions) {
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }

    public String getDefaultRoom() {
        return defaultRoom;
    }

    public void setDefaultRoom(String defaultRoom) {
        this.defaultRoom = defaultRoom;
    }

    public String getLoginPin() {
        return loginPin;
    }

    public void setLoginPin(String loginPin) {
        this.loginPin = loginPin;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

My UserRole class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLE")
public class UserRole {

    private String id;
    private User user;
    private String role;

    public UserRole() {

    }

    public UserRole(User user, String role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

As a reference I used the following tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/

EDIT: creation of the tables:
1) user_role:

```
    CREATE TABLE user_role
(
  id character varying NOT NULL,
  role character varying,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "user" FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

2) users:

```
    CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  user_id character varying(16) NOT NULL,
  user_name character varying(16),
  password character varying(16),
  first_name character varying(16),
  last_name character varying(16),
  voicemail_box character varying(16),
  default_room character varying(16),
  login_pin character varying(4),
  enabled boolean,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  CONSTRAINT users_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES user_settings (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Any answers are appreciated :) sorry if it is a duplicate question. I will mark it as duplicate as soon as I have a clue what causes the error. Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste the table structure for reference. The mapping seems correct.

Comment: show us also the hibernate properties please

Comment: Updated with the creation statements. :) Thank you!

Comment: `<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following thing

```
    CREATE TABLE user_role
(
  id character varying NOT NULL,
  role character varying,
  user_id character varying,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "user" FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

What you were missing was user_id column which has to be the foreign key, right now you have mapped your id field from your user_role table as both primary and foreign key.

Comment: When I try to create the table with this query I get an error:
`ERROR: relation "id" already exists
SQL state: 42P07` :(

Comment: you need to drop the earlier table and constraints then recreate using this query.

Comment: Thank you for the your answer! I did some mistake in the column relations. :) I also added the user_id as. Now it is fine.